Using "on par with" (or on a par with something) correctly

Overall, gas and coal were the two most significant sources of energy in both years. In addition, while petrol was on a par with gas and coal in terms of energy production in 1995, it was partly replaced by nuclear power and other sources in 2005.

First, Grammarly keeps suggesting that I should change on a par with to on par with, which is opposite to what dictionaries say. I suppose I should believe in dictionaries?
Second, I'd like to know if I'm using "on a par with" correctly here. To my mind, it means "to be as good/bad/important/... as something else". This is a useful phrase for me, but very often, what I think is natural turns out to be not suitable at all after asking native speakers. So, I just want to know if I've made a successful attempt to use this phrase here.


On a par with means 'at the same level as'. In British English it's always 'on a par', but on searching dictionary definitions (which you could have done for yourself) it appears that the 'a' is optional in American English. See this.

Thank you, Kate! Do you think I use the phrase naturally in my sentence?

I did look the phrase up on the Oxford, Cambridge, and Collin Dictionaries, all of which only show the phrase on a par with

The Cambridge link I gave you shows, if you scroll down, the phrase with 'a' in brackets labelled as American. Merriam-Webster also puts it in brackets. Yes, as the percentage for all three fuels is around 29% for 1995, the phrase is correctly used.

I'm American — I've never heard it used with "a", so as Kate says either way works. "On par with" sounds better if you have an American audience.
